# existing users suddenly unable to add new list items

Tags: 2013, permissions, app-permissions

I am using SharePoint 2013 as my company admin. We use 1 parent site and multiple sub-sites.

For the last couple of days, users that are on my parent site's "Members" list with the ability to edit are unable to add new items to a certain list using the "+ New Item" Link. when they click the link, they are getting an access denied message.

The users have the full ability to edit or delete any existing items, even add a new item when the list is in edit mode, but they cannot use the add new item link to access the new item form.

I have reviewed every permissions factor I can find on the site and in designer.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1):

Pick a few affected users.
Open your list settings and go to list settings and then use the "check permissions" button to validate their access.  If you are using custom permission sets - you need to be sure you have set what you think you set.  They need at least the Add and Edit Items permissions (plus all the permissions required to view the list and pages).

Check to see if you have broken inheritance (or are inheriting, but you want it broken).  Probably the most common thing I see happen is when something breaks inheritance and then deletes a group that had the required permission set assigned.